# get java field and method descriptors at runtime

Tags: java, reflection

The field and method descriptors are used by the runtime for linking classes. Consequently, they should be available through reflection. I need them for creating java classes at runtime. Is the only way to reconstruct the descriptors based on the information obtained through methods like Class.getName(), which returns almost, but not quite the descriptor for a field?

Comment: What do you mean by "descriptor"? Do you mean something other than the info available via JAVA's reflection library?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2 is the specification.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to get the descriptors seems to be to implement methods that derive that information from information available through reflection.

```
static String getDescriptorForClass(final Class c)
{
    if(c.isPrimitive())
    {
        if(c==byte.class)
            return "B";
        if(c==char.class)
            return "C";
        if(c==double.class)
            return "D";
        if(c==float.class)
            return "F";
        if(c==int.class)
            return "I";
        if(c==long.class)
            return "J";
        if(c==short.class)
            return "S";
        if(c==boolean.class)
            return "Z";
        if(c==void.class)
            return "V";
        throw new RuntimeException("Unrecognized primitive "+c);
    }
    if(c.isArray()) return c.getName().replace('.', '/');
    return ('L'+c.getName()+';').replace('.', '/');
}

static String getMethodDescriptor(Method m)
{
    String s="(";
    for(final Class c: m.getParameterTypes())
        s+=getDescriptorForClass(c);
    s+=')';
    return s+getDescriptorForClass(m.getReturnType());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ASM's `Type` has `getDescriptor` and `getMethodDescriptor`.

```
String desc = Type.getMethodDescriptor(method);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating and passing around strings, it is much better to use the interfaces found in the `java.lang.constant` package for this purpose.

See `ClassDesc`, `ConstantDescs`, `MethodTypeDesc`, etc.

These interfaces contain static factory methods that instantiate package-private classes that do the work.

`java.lang.Class` has a `describeConstable()` method which you can use as a starting point.

Comment: Why not `Class.descriptorString()` / `Class.describeConstable().orElseThrow()`?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn you are right, I changed my answer.

Comment: `descriptorString()` actually comes from `java.lang.invoke.TypeDescriptor.OfField` - which both `java.lang.constant.ClassDesc` and `java.lang.Class` implements.